# How can I add an alias to Ruby 1.9's Enocding.aliases?

Tags: ruby, encoding, character-encoding, ruby-1.9

Wanted to add an alias for one of the charsets that PayPal may use for its IPN (Instant Payment Notification).

This is silently ignored:

```
Encoding.aliases["x-mac-greek"] = "macGreek"
```

This doesn't work, either:

```
Encoding.aliases.update("x-mac-greek" => "macGreek")
```

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. If you look at [the source for the `aliases` method](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/v1_9_3_0/encoding.c#L1574-1582) you can see that it creates a new hash each time it's called, with the aliases copied into from the internal representation.

From what I can see it doesn't look like there's any way to modify this internal data from a Ruby program.

Perhaps you just need to check the string you get from PayPal before trying to use it as an encoding.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. What I'm trying to achieve isn't possible, that's clear.

Comment: How are these aliases loaded in Ruby? Is there a way to hook into that process to add more aliases?

Answer (score 1):

A following C extension will work:

```
#include <ruby.h>

extern VALUE rb_cEncoding;
int rb_encdb_alias(const char *alias, const char *orig);

/*
 * Add alias to an existing encoding
 *
 * Encoding.add_alias('hebrew', 'Windows-1255') -> 'hebrew'
 *
 */
VALUE rb_add_alias(VALUE self, VALUE alias,  VALUE orig)
{
    if (rb_encdb_alias(RSTRING_PTR(alias), RSTRING_PTR(orig)) == -1) {
        return Qnil;
    } else {
        return alias;
    }
}

void Init_enc_alias() {
    rb_define_singleton_method(rb_cEncoding, "add_alias", rb_add_alias, 2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can force a new definition of `Encoding.aliases`. It may or may be not useful for your purposes:I do not know if it will be picked up by other classes; it should but it may not.

```
Encoding.instance_eval <<__END
    alias :orig_aliases :aliases
    def aliases
        orig_aliases.update("x-mac-greek" => "macGreek")
    end
__END
```

Comment: This will only effect the array returned from `aliases`. The internal data structures that Ruby uses will remain unchanged. For example it won't allow you to do `"Foo".force_encoding("x-mac-greek")` - you get `ArgumentError: unknown encoding name - x-mac-greek`, the same as you would otherwise.

Comment: If `force_encoding` used the return value of `Encoding.aliases` it would had worked just fine. But it makes sense for such a frequently used method to take a shortcut and read the same internal data used to generate the original `Encoding.aliases` hash.